# Combining generic lists

Tags: c#

Right now I'm combining three lists with an union. I want to populate a GridView with the values, but the problem here is that in the list I want to separate the values. For example:

1. Listitem [0] "Firstname + " " + Lastname"
2. Listitem [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niFBa.png) employeeId
3. Listitem [2] "Second emp Firstname + " " + Second emp Lastname"
4. Listitem [3] Second emp employeeId

I want it to show on my GridView. This is my code at the moment:

```
List<string> ulist = _searchEmpList.Union(_searchTechSkillList).Union(_searchAssignList).ToList();
string s = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < ulist.Count; i++)
{
    s += ulist[i] + ",";
}

string[] split = s.Split(',');
DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = split[0]; //firstname + +lastname
dr["EmployeeId"] = split[1]; //employeeid

_dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Session["DataTableSearch"] = _dt;

GridViewSearchResults.DataSource = _dt;
GridViewSearchResults.DataBind();
```

[image]

Comment: What is going wrong exactly? In the code you posted, you split on `,` but in your text you explain all words are splitted by a space.

Comment: When i save to the three lists i save like i say in text, but then i want to split theese items with a ',' like i do, because in datarow Name i just want firstname + " " + lastname to show up. and in the row employeeid i want the empid to show up

Comment: I want to make an loop on the split and put the values on respective gridview column

Comment: is there a special need to Union this Lists and get a messy List<string> ? why not creating an Class Employee and using List<Employee> instead ..?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the desired output?

Comment: @DaveBish desired output will properly be an single Employee in each row of his DataTable

Comment: Yeah I agree with @WiiMaxx, you should really create an `Employee`-class...

Comment: Check my edit, ive put an image there with the result

Comment: @WiiMaxx, So i should create a class. Could you provide with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why you're going to all that trouble. The following will do what you say you want. Whether it's what you really want is a different question.

```
List<string> ulist = _searchEmpList.Union(_searchTechSkillList).Union(_searchAssignList).ToList();
int i = 0;
while (i < ulist.Count-1)
{
    DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = ulist[i]; //firstname + +lastname
    dr["EmployeeId"] = ulist[i+1]; //employeeid
    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ++i;
}
```

That duplicates the logic in your original code, with the loop that you asked for. Whether it's going to give you the results you think it should is an open question. `Union` combines the two lists and creates a new list with *distinct* values. So if there are any duplicate values in the two lists, they'll only show up once in the result.

Also, `Union` makes no guarantee about the order of items in the final list.

Comment: So if I add Kristian Svensson and Kristian Olsson it will only show one result if I work with union?

Comment: No, "Kristian Svensson" and "Kristian Olsson" are unique strings. But if the first list had `{"Kristian", "Svensson"}` and the second list had `{"Kristian", "Olsson"}`, the result of union would be `{"Kristian", "Svensson", "Olsson"}`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example you where asking for ^^

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace simpleOO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var myEmployee = new List<Employee>();

            var fistEmployee = new Employee();

            fistEmployee.FirstName = "Filip";
            fistEmployee.LastName = "Göndek";
            fistEmployee.TechSkills.Add(new TechSkills(){Skill="Engish"});
            fistEmployee.Id=1;
            myEmployee.Add(fistEmployee);
            myEmployee.Add(new Employee()
                                           {
                                               Id = 2,
                                               FirstName = "Helmut",
                                               LastName = "Müller",
                                               TechSkills = new List<TechSkills>()
                                                                                {
                                                                                    new TechSkills(){Skill="Engish"},
                                                                                    new TechSkills(){Skill="Spain"}
                                                                                }
                                           }
                                           );

            var filteredList = myEmployee.Where(employee => employee.TechSkills.Any(skill => skill.Skill == "Spain")).ToList();

            var bList = new BindingList<Employee>(filteredList);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bList;
        }




    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        private List<TechSkills> techSkills = new List<TechSkills>();
        public List<TechSkills> TechSkills
        {
            get { return techSkills; }
            set { techSkills = value; }
        }

        // what ever more you need ...
    }

    public class TechSkills
    {
        public string Skill { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i know it is very simple and dirty but i think you get what i want to tell you ;)